# Is there really microfilm on the Moon?

Tags: apollo-program, identify-this-object, lunar-landing, astronaut-lifestyle

A comment below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12247/12102) to *Disc mounted on lunar rover?* suggests that

> ...a number of documented microfilms that were on the Apollo missions.

meaning I presume that bits of microfilm were physically aboard Apollo missions (not that the written material was on (i.e. about) the Moon), and the context suggesting that some of these made it to the proximity of the Moon or perhaps even landing.

What is the nature of the Apollo microfilm? Were astronauts provided microfilm readers? Or was it souvenir type material similar to postage stamps? Was it provided to trade (along with chocolates, nylons and cigarettes<sup>1</sup>) with the locals for safe passage home?

Did any microfilm make it to lunar orbit or the lunar surface? Was any then left there amongst all the other thing that remained there in order to save weight for the return to Earth?

<sup>1</sup> [K-ration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ration) and an episode of [Hogan's Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogan%27s_Heroes) I once saw.

Comment: Now asked: [How (the heck) was coherent synthetic aperture radar (SAR) implemented using photographic emulsion aboard Apollo 17?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46941)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

According to the official [list of items left on the moon by Apollo](https://history.nasa.gov/FINAL%20Catalogue%20of%20Manmade%20Material%20on%20the%20Moon.pdf), Apollo 15 left a

> Microfilm roll containing Apollo 11 Manned Flight Awareness booklet

"Manned Flight Awareness" was a program designed to heighten employee sensitivity to the fact that real people were flying on the vehicles they worked on. It produced motivational posters and booklets, and had an awards program. Much of the material featured Peanuts comic characters (the highest award is called the Silver Snoopy). Sometime in the late 1980s it was renamed to "Space Flight Awareness".

The following image shows some representative Manned Flight Awareness posters. It is not intended to convey the content of the microfilm.

[image]

Image Source: [Heritage Auctions](http://ha.com)

Comment: Wow they had color microfilm! ;-)

Comment: Now I want to ask if there was ever color microfilm, but I don't think there are any SE sites for such a question (such = silly).

Comment: @uhoh I remember reading old magazine issues in the university library on microfilm. I can't remember if it was color or not. I sort of thought it was, but it's been a long time.  Maybe that was microfiche, though, it probably was.

Answer (score 9):

The Lunar Sounder was a radar experiment contained in the service module experiment bay during Apollo 17.  The results were recorded on microfilm while in orbit around the moon, and the film cassette was retrieved with a spacewalk by the command module pilot (Ronald Evans) during the trip back to Earth:

> The lunar sounder experiment, flown on the Apollo 17 mission, obtained electromagnetic soundings of the moon for use in developing a selenological three-dimensional model to a depth of about 1.3 kilometers.  The equipment was installed in the service module and consisted of a coherent synthetic aperature radar, the associated antennas, and an **optical recorder**.  The radar system operated in the two RF bands of 5 megahertz (HF 1) and 15 megahertz (HF 2), or in the VHF band of 150 megahertz, and transmitted a series of swept frequency pulses.  A small part of the pulse energy was reflected from the lunar surface and subsurface features and subsequently was detected by a receiver on the spacecraft.  The radar video output from the receiver was **recorded by the optical recorder on film**, and the film cassette was retrieved during the transearth extravehicular activity.
>
> [*Apollo Program Summary Report*](https://history.nasa.gov/apsr/Apollopt2-2.pdf), section 3.3.4

Microfilm was not used to take *actual photographs*.  [*Apollo Experience Report: Photographic Equipment and Operations*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19720025202) describes the type of film used to take pictures, and only conventional film is listed.

Other than the Lunar Sounder and conventional film for photography, there is no other film listed in the [stowage lists](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-stowage.html).

Comment: Are you sure the optical recorder used microfilm? The report does not contain that word and there is no information about the film format used for the recorder.

Comment: Wow, that's an extremely Kerbalesque data-retrieval method

Comment: @llama Optical data recording on film was a fairly common technique in field scientific instrumentation in those days: mechanically simpler, denser, and less power-hungry than magnetic recording.

Comment: @JohnDoty right, but I would have guessed that you'd have some mini-airlock system to retrieve the film without requiring a whole EVA. I guess that's just more potential points of failure though.

Comment: @Uwe: It doesn't outright use the term microfilm.  However, over 10 hours of synthetic aperture radar data was recorded on a single film cassette.

Comment: They may have used 8, 16, 35 or 70 mm perforated film. But to store over 10 hours of synthetic aperture radar data, you do not need film length, you need film area, length * width. The ratio of perforation to used film area may be better for a 70 mm film compared to a 8 mm. So to get most film area into a single cassette, a 70 mm film may be more efficient.

Comment: It was Kodak s0-394 film, whatever that is. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42890437.pdf

Comment: Hmm... something is *questionable* here (i.e. has the ability to generate a new SE question). I think (checking now) that by the sound of it coherent SAR must record phase information, meaning it must have been a pretty sophisticated system in order to put that into photographic emulsion and later read it back on the ground and do the interferometry. Wow!

Comment: thus [How (the heck) was coherent synthetic aperture radar (SAR) implemented using photographic emulsion? (Apollo 17)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46941/12102)

Comment: According to this https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42890462.pdf s0-394 is 70mm film, as @Uwe speculated.